# Isomorphisms and Order of Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I don't fully understand the solution to the following problem. The way that isomorphisms were defined in my abstract algebra class was the following (I'm paraphrasing) :

A function, $\phi$, establishes an isomorphism between two groups if $\phi$ is bijective and establishes a homomorphism between the two groups. I can't seem how this relates to the order of elements in the groups other than perhaps $f(a*b) = f(a)f(b)$ failing to be true when $a=b=-1$.

Comment: If $\phi $ is an iso it will take an element x of order n to an element $\phi(x)$ of order n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, and suppose $\varphi: G \to H$ is an isomorphism. Then it is easy to show that for all $g \in G$, if the order of $g$ is $m$, then the order of $\varphi(g)$ must also be $m$.

The proof in the book may be rephrased as a proof by contradiction. Suppose for a contradiction that $\psi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^*$ is an isomorphism. Since $\psi$ is surjective, there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\psi(x)=-1$.

But $x$ has infinite order in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence $-1$ has infinite order in $\mathbb{R}^*$. But $(-1)^2=1$, a contradiction since $1$ is the identity in $\mathbb{R}^*$. Therefore the two groups are not isomorphic.